# How do I run my own bower server

Tags: bower

I'd like to run my own bower server to start sharing a couple of internal modules across teams.  I'm having a very hard time finding the information for running your own server.  On the bower.io site there is this line

> N.B. To run your own Bower Endpoint for custom packages that are
>   behind a firewall, you can use a simple implementation of the Bower
>   Server.

With a link to [Bower Server](https://github.com/bower/registry)

Do I simply clone that repo and 'run it'? I'm not a ruby guy at all so I'm not even sure what run it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That repo is a Sinatra app, so you need to `git clone` it, run `bundle install` in its directory, and run 'ruby application.rb`.  Comment on this answer if you need more details.

There is also a node server, which I have never used and cannot comment on its quality - https://npmjs.org/package/bower-server

I guess there is a PHP one also - https://github.com/indieisaconcept/slim-bower-server

EDITS:

Some links for Ruby n00bs

- http://bundler.io/
- http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html